# Activate some menu using single key without pressing enter

Tags: keyboard, menu-bar

I want to minimize number of keystrokes to access menu items. One needs to press enter after activating some menu using keyboard. Is it possible to open the menu items in a menu without pressing enter?

Answer (score 1):

[**Keyboard Maestro**](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) can do this using a macro such as this:

[image: Select … in the Menu … in …]